# AnimationTimer for each animation or main animation loop and pulse system?

Tags: animation, javafx-2, game-engine

I'm working on game engine in JavaFX and right now i'm using a `AnimationTimer` object for each sprite and everythings works fine.

But i want to know what is the best aprroach? Having one main loop which call update method of sprites each time or have dedicated loop (`AnimationTimer`) for each sprite?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All animations in FX are already using inner pulse system.

So unless you want to manually adjust pulse engine (frequency, processor load influence, etc) you can safely use `AnimationTimer`.